# Which operator in rxjs can get the last call in the Observable?

Tags: rxjs

how to get the last result of async operation to my subscribe function and cancel the previous events?

I have a button that call to `makeRequest` function which return `Observable` like this:

```
makeRequest() {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      let uniqueId = this.uniqueId++;

      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('[makeRequest] complete request ' + uniqueId);
        observer.next({ save: true, id: uniqueId });
        observer.complete();
      }, 5000);
    });
  }
```

In my subscribe function I get the results like this:

```
this.makeRequest().subscribe(r => {
  console.log({ r });
});
```

How to get the last event from `makeRequest`, even I click multiple times on the button?

```
- button clicked (uniqId = 0)
- button clicked (uniqId = 1)
- button clicked (uniqId = 2)
- subscribe(r => r // is uniqId = 2)
```

all my previous events was ignore but not this one.

Comment: What do you mean "last event"? Every time you create another observable, there could be an infinite number of them, which one is last?

Comment: the last is uniqId = 2, because this was uniqId value when I stop click on the button..

Comment: What if you click the button once more? Is the `uniqId = 2` still last? No, there is no `rxjs` operator which says "emit once the user decides to stop clicking the button".

Comment: Ohhh.. until it's complete :) for example when I entered to subscribe function then I start to new cycle again

Comment: Each of them is complete...